# NoReverseMatch at URL

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to create a movie survey in Django for an assignment, and I am currently working on the function. I can't seem to understand why won't it recognize the URL I pass.

I tried removing the hardcoded URL as shown in the Django tutorial on the framework's site, but that doesn't make the error go away.

Here's an excerpt from urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    path('movie=<int:movie_id>&user=<int:user_id>/', views.movie, name='movie'),
    path('ratings/', views.ratings, name='movie'),
    path('rating/<int:movie_id>/', views.rating, name='movie'),
    path('movie=<int:movie_id>&user=<int:user_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('register/',views.register, name='register'),
]
```

This is my movie view( supposed to present a movie and a star rating radio for the user to rate the movie), where the URL is constructed and passed to HTML:

```
def movie(request,movie_id,user_id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk=movie_id)
    voteURL = '/polls/movie=' + str(movie_id) + '&user='+str(user_id)+'/vote/'
    context = {
        'mymoviecaption':movie.Title,
        'moviePoster': 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original'+tmdb.Movies(movie.TMDBID).images().get('posters')[0].get('file_path'),
        'myrange': range(10,0,-1),
        'myuserid':user_id,
        'voteurl': voteURL,
        'mymovieid':movie_id
    }
    #print(nextURL)
    translation.activate('en')
    return HttpResponse(render(request, 'movieview.html', context=context))
```

The HTML excerpt, where the vote view is called:

```
<form action="{% url voteurl %}" method="post">

    {% for i in myrange %}
        <input id="star-{{i}}" type="radio" name="rating" value={{i}}>
            <label for="star-{{i}}" title="{{i}} stars">
                <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit">Vote!</input>
</form>
```

The vote view( should save to database and redirect to the next movie, doesn't save to database yet, because I didn't want to clutter it with records until I am sure I got the function to work):

```
def vote(request, movie_id,user_id):
    try:
        nextmovie=get_object_or_404(Movie, pk=movie_id+1)
        nextURL = '/polls/movie=' + str(movie_id + 1) + '&user='+str(user_id)+'/'
    except Http404:
        nextURL = '/polls/ratings'
    try:
        myrating = int(request.POST['rating'])
        print(myrating)
    except:
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, '/polls/movie=' + str(movie_id + 1) + '&user='+str(user_id)+'/', {
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    return HttpResponseRedirect(nextURL)
```

No matter what I try, I get the NoReverseMatch at /polls/movie=1&user=9/ whenever I try to load the first movie page, despite said URL being defined in urlpatterns.

Comment: You are confusing different paradigms for passing arguments to views. Paths and querystrings are not interchangeable as you try to do in `path('movie=<int:movie_id>&user=<int:user_id>/'`. I suggest you to follow a Django tutorial **from the beginning to the end** and try to understand what is going on, instead of copying/pasting random excerpts from different tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way how you provide two pk in the urls

It should be like this

```
path('movie/<int:movie_id>/<int:user_id>/', views.movie, name='movie'),
```

Also this is not the way of providing url in the template so it should be something like this

```
<form action="{% url 'vote' %}" method="post">
 # {% url 'url_name' %}
  # if app_name provided {% url 'app_name:url_name' %}
```

And please follow the tutorials step by step